# Add 2nd internal/private ip address to google cloud vm instance

Tags: cloud, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

How can I add a 2nd internal/private ip address to a google cloud vm instance?

Answer (score 2):

You can configure a static network address, where you can combine routes and an the 'can_ip_forward' ability. Take a look at this page https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/instances-and-network#staticnetworkaddress

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/configure-instance-ip-addresses#assigninternalip only discusses adding extra external IP addresses to instances.  The only mention of internal IP addresses is about defining a desired internal IP address on instance creation.  However it does not mention how to add extra internal ip addresses at all.